# Trapping an error in python

Tags: python, error-handling

I am trying to trap error and let the code finish running. 
In the code below,  I "do Something." if fails, I want to print Error Msg 
and continue running the second half.

What is happening is When an error occurs with the first section, The error statement print and 
stops running. I would like the code to keep running past the first section.

```
  if len(rows) > 0:
            try:                
                print "Do something"       
            except:
                print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")  

            try:
                print "Do somethings else"
            except:
                print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python's exceptions don't have a built-in restart capability to "continue running the second half".  Instead, you just need to move the "unconditional, always do this" part out of the try-clause and into a finally-clause or outside the try-statement altogether.

P.S.  It is usually ill-advised to swallow all exceptions with a bare except-clause.  Instead,  the usual best practice is to catch only the exceptions you know how to handle.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Can you programmatically determine if 'do Something' failed? If so, that's a better way to go rather than just relying on an exception handling mechanism. I see this anti-pattern a lot in .net code. Exceptions, in many languages, are intended for exceptional circumstances, not just error handling.</s>

Keeping answer just to preserve comments for those who might think like I did.

Comment: The "exceptions are just for the exceptional" rule is something that applies to other languages.  In Python, exceptions are routinely used for control flow.

Comment: Valid point, after some research I see your reasoning. Feels strange to me, however.

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl has a writeup on why it's a rule in other languages, and points out why exceptions are used for control flow in python.